# Is there a way to store one of the two type value in mongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to store an image or a link(String), how can I define that in the mongoose Schema

Comment: Image and links are both different types of data, so you'll have to take different variables for them.

You can make an object of image details and then under that object keep the two data types as you like.

Comment: Can a field have either image or String type of data? Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: There is no "Image" type in Mongo. Not sure why you would want to store an image itself in a database, but if for some reason you have to, I guess you can convert it to Base64 and store it as a string